# Can someone without read/write SQL access still see power query tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, powerquery

I have sent an email to a person with an Excel workbook that is populated via power query. Will the recipient be able to see/ edit the content within the workbook? Will it refresh as a dynamic query? I do not know their SQL permission level, but am highly doubtful they have read access let alone write access.

Comment: It isn't the permission for the user viewing the document, it is the permission of the user making the connection. Meaning the user in your connection string. If that is using Windows auth then it would in fact be the end user.

Comment: It's possible to send Excel Workbooks that both do and do not allow refreshing data or accessing the underlying table, so we don't have enough information here to answer this without getting our hands on the Workbook.

Comment: If you share a `pbix` or `xlsx` set to`import mode`, they can open and see the cached data. However, they can't modify the query or refresh it without the connection. Depending on security levels, some versions might not even get the cached data